# Applying stream sequence on a slice in go using ghemawat/stream

Tags: go, stream, slice

Assume that you have a slice `items` and you want to apply a sequence of stream operations on this slice using stream package: [ghemawat/stream](https://github.com/ghemawat/stream). how one can do this? to my knowledge the only way to give a stream sequence string input is to use `stream.items(items ...string)` which can't be used on slices.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use the trick below:
we start by using `stream.Numbers(1, len(items))` and adding a map filter `stream.Map(fn func(string) string)` like this:

```
package main

import("strconv")

func main() {
    sliceStreamExample()
}

func sliceStreamExample() {
    items := []string{"foo", "bar"} // define a sample slice
    
    stream.Run { // using Map to and Numbers to emit the slice content
        stream.Numbers(1, len(items)),
        stream.Map(func(num string) string {
            return items[strconv.Atoi(num)]
        }),
        stream.WriteLines(os.Stdout)
    }
}
```

output:

```
foo
bar
```

I don't know if its the optimal way or not. please share your solution if you found an easier one! thanks.